# Flagging in trash

Tags: support, chat

I just went into the trash section and post some messages there. And I saw that the messages moved to trash could be flagged. So, is the flagging system works in trash too?

Comment: What is the "trash section"?

Comment: @Oded http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48058/trash

Comment: That's just a normal chat room that has been named "Trash". I guess people are using it as a target for removal of unwanted chat messages.

Comment: @Oded Yes, I noticed that. So if someone flag messages there, will the moderators be notified?

Comment: @berserk Since it's just a regular room like all the others, yes.

Comment: Wow, all this time I thought the "trash section" was the home page.

Comment: @CodyGray lolwut?

Answer (score 3):

> I just went into the trash section and post some messages there. And I saw that 
>       the messages moved to trash could be flagged. So, is the flagging system works in
>       trash too?

There is nothing like Trash Section in chat rooms. The link you shared for Trash section is nothing but a general chat room. Users use it to move unwanted messages. 
So of-course, flagging system and all chat room functions will work.

tbh, it's completely a **non-sense question.**

Comment: T.T Anyways, what I mean was what if people start flagging messages there?

Comment: @berserk it will be handles like in every other chat room too. The difference is that those rooms are normally just never entered.

Comment: @rekire What if someone start flagging messages there? It will bother moderators right?

Comment: @berserk yes of cause. Same rules for all rooms.

Comment: @rekire *evil look*.... Just kidding :D

Comment: Code formatting is for code. We have block quotes, use them when you're quoting, please.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot. :) and Thanks for the edit. BTW I am a baby :D